# How do I get the user's State Tree in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

After reading the Angular 2 [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) and [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), I was led to believe that the [`RouterState`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterState-interface.html) class contained the [state](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/145672529346/angular-router) of the user's progression through the app. By that I mean I expected it to contain a tree where each node was a route taken by the user. This is not the case. The [`RouterState`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterState-interface.html) class does not contain any past state.

After reading [this](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/145672529346/angular-router) post, I'm convinced there is a way to parse out a state tree from the router state class. But I'm trying to avoid writing it myself. Ideally what I'm looking for is this:

```
state:
    name: '3rd state'
    url: '/my/state/3'
    parent:
        name: '2nd state'
        url: '/my/state/2'
        parent:
            name: '1st state'
            url: '/my/state/1'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't past routes form a list, not a tree?  When I've needed this (the list, anyway), I've recorded routes in my own structure on locationChangeStart.

Comment: First, history like that is typically represented as a list, not a tree.  Second, when that article talks about a URL tree they are talking about the tree like configuration of available routes (e.g. from route /foo I can get to /foo/bar and /foo/baz).  Finally, angular doesn't keep track of history.  There is a history API in the browser that you might be able to use.  What problem are you trying to solve?